# How do you convert a datetime type (of Jython) to java.util.Date?

Tags: python, jython

I am new to Jython, how do you convert a datetime type (of Jython) to java.util.Date?

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware of this:

> java.util.Date.getTime() gives the milliseconds since the epoch while Jython (just like CPython) gives seconds since the epoch. So you need to divide the values given from java.util.Date by 1000

From Jython's [FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/ProgrammingJython#How_can_I_manipulate_a_java.util.Date_object_in_Jython.3F)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
from java.util import Calendar, GregorianCalendar

def datetimeToJavaDate(value):
    cal = GregorianCalendar(value.year, value.month - 1, value.day, 
        value.hour, value.minute, value.second)
    cal.set (Calendar.MILLISECOND, value.microsecond / 1000)
    return cal.getTime()
```

Comment: How would you support timezones?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of messing around and experimenting with this... these two methods are the ones I use, for conversion to java.sql.Timestamp and then in the other direction, using java.sql.Timestamp.time() (ms since 1/1/1970).

"bst" here stands for British Summer Time... I did at the time verify that it correctly took such dates into account: i.e. it would appear that the tz module is sufficiently clever to be able to detect that months during the summer are subject to BST and adjust accordingly.

Hopefully it should work with any other time zones you can throw at it...

```
def convert_datetime_bst_to_javaSQLTimestamp( datetime_val ):
    if datetime_val is None: return None
    assert type( datetime_val ) is datetime.datetime
    tz_local = tz.tzlocal()
    gmt_datetime = datetime_val - tz_local.dst( datetime_val )
    delta = gmt_datetime - datetime.datetime( 1970, 1, 1 )
    seconds = int( delta.total_seconds() ) 
    ms_fraction = int( delta.microseconds / 1000 )
    ms = seconds * 1000 + ms_fraction
    return java.sql.Timestamp( ms )

def conv_ms_to_datetime_bst( ms ):
    assert type( ms ) is long, '# ms type %s' % ( type( ms ), )
    # NB potentially a problem with pre-1970 and post-2038 dates: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000.0)
    gmt_datetime = datetime.datetime( 1970, 1, 1 ) + datetime.timedelta( 0, 0, 0, ms )
    tz_local = tz.tzlocal()
    return gmt_datetime + tz_local.dst( gmt_datetime )
```